# Modify next_posts_link( ); URL in Wordpress to include #hash extension

Tags: php, wordpress

Am looking for a good method to add a **#hash** to **Wordpress Paged Navigation**

The basic code, something like this

```
<nav id="<?php echo $html_id; ?>" class="navigation" role="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li class="previous">
             <?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">Load more</span>', '' ) ); ?>
       </li>
  </ul>
```

**Output**

```
http://myurl.com/page/2/
```

**Problem**

Am running 3 individual queries on index page so i would need to add a #hash to the url to make it load the right content. Am looking for a built in function or other smart / light way of achieving a url for my next_posts_link( ); looking something like this

```
http://myurl.com/page/2/#hash
```

Have been looking around but most solutions gravitate around breaking it apart, modify and rebuild. It works well but am thinking there must be a better way!!

Any smart suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
add_filter('next_post_link', 'changemylink');

function changemylink($link) 
{
    //you can also do some checks here, like if you want it to only be replaced on specific page or for specific post type, etc
    return preg_replace('#(href=["\']?[^"\'>]+)(["\']?)#','$1#yourtag$2',$output)
}
```

Comment: Show me what you have in mind. Have been looking at several regex way's that for sure works well but i want to keep light and out of functions.php if possible.

Comment: @MathiasÅsberg  Like `return preg_replace('#(href=["\']?[^"\'>]+)(["\']?)#','$1#yourtag$2',$output);` for example.