# Filtering WordPress next_post_link_(), and previous_post_link() function

Tags: php, wordpress

I need help with filtering the `next_post_link()`, and `previous_post_link()` functions in WordPressss. I would like it to only show next/previous post with the same field answer as the current field.

I have a custom field set on the post type that is a $post_object.

The admin creates content for the post and chooses a category from a `post_object drop down field`.

These `next_post_link()`, and `previous_post_link()` buttons are going on top of my `/single-featured_project/ (single-post_type)` page.

Thank you for all your help :),
Happy Coding

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying featured project single posts.
 *
 * @package understrap
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

get_header();
?>
<?php
    the_post();

        $cat = '';
          $cat = get_the_category();
          if (is_array($cat))
              $cat = $cat[0];
?>

<section class="featured-project-header" style="background-color: #13293C; padding-top: 6rem; padding-bottom: 1rem;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box" style="display: flex; align-items:center;">
           <img style="max-height: 22px;" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Symbol-6-–-1@2x.png">
           <span class="featured-project-title"><h1 class="mb-0">&nbsp<?php  the_title();?></h1></span>
        </div>
        <h3 style="margin-left: 55px;" class="featured-project-location"><?php echo do_shortcode('[acf field="location"]'); ?></h3>
        <!-- Displays Project Category to Filter By -->
        <?php

            $post_object = get_field('project_category');

            if( $post_object ):

                // override $post
                $post = $post_object;
                setup_postdata( $post );

                ?>

                <?php the_title(); ?>


                    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <!-- Ends Project Category to Filter By -->
        <div class="float-right"><?php next_post_link(); ?></div>
        <div class="float-left"><?php previous_post_link(); ?></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hmm, I guess it's not really a duplicate, the filters you need to use are on those questions I found, but I think you'll need to couple those with a `pre_get_posts` filter... Questions with `next_` and `previous_` filters: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36479870/adding-google-analytics-to-wordpress-next-post-link-function), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32296874/modify-next-posts-link-url-in-wordpress-to-include-hash-extension) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542739/how-to-customize-wordpress-internal-functions-like-adjacent-post-link)

Comment: I still have not been able to filter the posts with pre_get_posts

Comment: Research here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=next_post_link+pre_get_posts